# in_app_purchases plugin , it shows blank bottom sheets when make purchases.(Flutter android app)

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

(On Android)I am Using "in_app_purchase: ^3.1.8" and "testing SKU id" to implement inApp purchases to my flutter application, but when buyProduct() called, it shows blank bottom sheet.

Here is My code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

import '../../../storage/sharde_preference.dart';
import '../../../utils/const.dart';

//import for GooglePlayPurchaseDetails
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/in_app_purchase_android.dart';

class LockScreenController extends GetxController{

  final String categoryName = Get.arguments;

  final InAppPurchase inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

  late StreamSubscription<dynamic> subscription;

  List<String> productId = <String>[
    ANDROID_PURCHASE_SKU,
  ];

  // Is the API available on the device
  RxBool isApiAvailable = true.obs;

  RxBool isProVersion = false.obs;

  // Products for sale
  RxList<ProductDetails> products = <ProductDetails>[].obs;

  // Past purchases
  RxList<PurchaseDetails> purchases = <PurchaseDetails>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {

    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;

    subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      listenToPurchaseUpdate(purchaseDetailsList);
    },onDone: (){
      subscription.cancel();
    },onError: (error){
      log(error.toString(), name: "ERROR");
    }
    );

    initialize();

    super.onInit();
  }

  //buy product
  void buyProduct(ProductDetails productDetails) async {

    // Log product details to verify they are correct.
    log("Product ID: ${productDetails.id}, Title: ${productDetails.title}, Price: ${productDetails.price}");

    final PurchaseParam param = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: param,);

  }

  initialize() async {

    // Check availability of In App Purchases
    isApiAvailable.value = await inAppPurchase.isAvailable();

    if(isApiAvailable.value){
      await getProducts();
      if(Platform.isAndroid){
        // await getPastPurchases();
        // verifyPurchases();
      }
    }
  }

  //get all products
  Future<void> getProducts () async {

    // Set<String> ids = Set.from({ANDROID_PURCHASE_SKU});

    ProductDetailsResponse response = await inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productId.toSet());

    products.addAll(response.productDetails);

    log(" description:${products.first.description} id: ${products.first.id} title: ${products.first.title} price: ${products.first.price}", name: "PRODUCTS");
  }

  //get past purchases
  Future getPastPurchases() async {
    await inAppPurchase.restorePurchases(
      applicationUserName: Platform.packageConfig
    );
  }

  //product is purchased or not
  PurchaseDetails hasPurchased(String productID) {
    return purchases.firstWhere((purchase) => purchase.productID == productID);
  }

  //to verify purchases
  void verifyPurchases () {
    for (var product in products){
      PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails = hasPurchased(product.id);

      if(purchaseDetails != null && purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased){
        log("_________PURCHASED", name: 'PRODUCT STATUS');
        SharedPreference().saveBoolean(PREFKEY_ISPURCHASE, true);
        isProVersion = true.obs;
        update();
      }else{
        log('_________NOT PURCHASED', name: "PRODUCT STATUS");
        SharedPreference().saveBoolean(PREFKEY_ISPURCHASE, false);
        isProVersion = false.obs;
        update();
      }
    }
  }


  //listen on purchases update
  Future<void> listenToPurchaseUpdate(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {

    for(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        //print("Pending");
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          SharedPreference().saveBoolean(PREFKEY_ISPURCHASE, true);
          isProVersion = true.obs;
          verifyPurchases();
          update();
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          if (purchaseDetails.error?.message ==
              PurchaseStatus.purchased.name) {
            SharedPreference().saveBoolean(PREFKEY_ISPURCHASE, true);
            isProVersion = true.obs;
            update();
          }
        }
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {

            final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
            inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<
                InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
            await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);

        }
        if(purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase){
          await inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }

      }
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();

    subscription.cancel();
  }

}
```

[the expected output something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w05gV.png)the output I am expecting is it gives a purchase details page from google to make payment